# printing with metallic ink on uncoated stock

Tags: print-design, pantone

Is it possible to print using pantone 877u on uncoated stock and varnish the area, in a way to achieve the effect of pantone 877c?

Comment: Hi n1k, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. This sounds like an excellent question to ask your printer! If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I do not thing metalic ink will look good on uncoated paper. Ask the printer to make a test, a simple test smudgin on the target paper you need will give tou an idea.

Answer (score 2):

The letter at the end of the pantone number U and C are just artificial rendering of the metallic ink on coated and uncoated paper for your display.

Your printer will use the same can of pantone 877 ink no matter the 877U or 877C you chose for your design!

So if you want to know and see how the final result will look like once printed, you should look at an official pantone color book or ask your printer to show you examples of printed projects using that metallic ink on the type of paper (coated or uncoated) you plan to use, with varnish or not.

Note that the varnish will not affect much the color of the metallic ink if it's applied on top of it. What makes the coated and uncoated ink color vary is how the ink "sinks" in the paper.

You can still print the metallic on top of a varnished zone, on an uncoated paper. It creates an original effect, a bit like a spot varnish would. If it's a thick UV varnish, the metallic should be closer to the effect created on a coated paper but the ink might look matte.

This can work because metallic inks are more opaque than the other colored inks in offset printing.

Might be simpler and nicer to use a coated paper, and a spot varnish that is matte, if the budget allows it, and it's the effect you're looking for.

Comment: I don't think UV is a good indea on an uncoated paper... I have never tryed that.

Comment: That's not uncommon at all, maybe you're missing on something. One day you'll get a request for an effect that requires combo you have never tried but look amazingly good and works. It's easier of course to be able to have access to the machines and make tests when you actually work in a print place or when you have a very close relationship to your printer. Otherwise it's expensive to test things and you're on you own!

Comment: As I have good relation with the printer guys, I can make some tests. I'll test some uncoated sheets of paper on my next UV project.

Answer (score 1):

No, the varnish will not bring back the gloss that you get when print on a coated paper. In fact, varnish will only act as a protection against smudges and not gloss the ink at all or at best very very little.